# Android Graphics Library

Tags: android, transform, graphic

I need suggestion for Android library for graphics, for transformation images , anchor points, rotate , warp , scale etc. Project is something like photoshop also has 2 - 3 simple animation . So I need from someone to recommend to me a library which suit for me :). Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need more of a lib, so here goes some!

**Cropper**

https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

**GPUImage for Android**

https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

**PhotoProcessing**

https://github.com/lightbox/PhotoProcessing

See more here, You can filter by img

http://android-arsenal.com/tag/47

Comment: Thank you , but i need more for transformation :) ( Anchor Points, Perspective Transform, Skew , Warp ) etc.